# Write file names from loop to text file

Tags: powershell

```
$fileEntries = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles("C:\Users\U0146121\Desktop\Example Data"); #where the file is located.
foreach($fileName in $fileEntries) 
{ 
 #write the file name to a text file.  
}
```

I need to write the file name to a text file within the loop but I'm not sure how to.

Eventually I will read the text file and search the filenames in excel. But for now I have to write the .txt file first.

Comment: Are you wanting the name of a bunch of files in a directory?

Comment: yeah just the file name

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tested this, and it worked for me:

```
Get-childitem -path "C:\" -recurse -name | out-file C:\Output.txt
```

Comment: Is there anyways to output it to the text file without the header and spaces?